# PowerShell hangs after Azure command confirmation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a script to delete containers in Azure Container Instances. The command is the following:

```
az container delete --resource-group myResourceX --name myContainerX
```

In a regular console that command asks to confirm the operation with y or n. But in my script after that line, it hangs and won't do anything (I have to close the editor). My intention was to keep executing the following lines to emulate the y, but it never reaches them:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate("ACI management");
Start-Sleep -s 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('y');
```

Comment: Do you need to leverage the `wscript.shell` API, or can you use the `--yes` flag? Note the details: `--yes -y            : Do not prompt for confirmation.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of preventing the system from hanging would be to send the `--yes` flag into the CLI. This may not achieve the same goal if the system is architected around `wscript.shell`.

For example:

```sh
az container delete --resource-group myResourceX --name myContainerX --yes
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that flag and it solves the problem. But anyone looking for the answer to PowerShell hangs after an command asking confirmation, might not find the answer. Should I delete it instead?